# MakeSignature.signDetached throws No Such Algorithm exception (SUN provider & SHA-256)

Tags: itext, sha256

I am trying to digitally sign a PDF document with iText. Since I will be using a hardware encryptor with JCE provider eventually I am also trying to test getting rid of BountyCastle in my unit test and instead use the default SUN implementation for the time being (until the hardware encryptor arrives).

However, I get the following exception when I run my program:

Exception in thread "main" java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: SHA256 for provider SUN
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getService(GetInstance.java:87)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:206)
    at java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:698)
    at java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance(MessageDigest.java:215)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.DigestAlgorithms.getMessageDigest(DigestAlgorithms.java:159)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.ProviderDigest.getMessageDigest(ProviderDigest.java:61)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeSignature.signDetached(MakeSignature.java:130)
    at SignDoc.signPdf(SignDoc.java:142)
    at SignDoc.main(SignDoc.java:182)

The last few lines of codes are as below:

```
    //ExternalSignature es = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, "SHA-256", "BC");
    //ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
    //ExternalSignature es = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, "SHA-256", "SUN");
    ExternalSignature es = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, "SHA-256", "SunRsaSign");
    ExternalDigest digest = new ProviderDigest("SUN");
    MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, es, chain, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);
```

As you can see, I am just copying the samples and changed the provider name and the call 'new BouncyCastleDigest()' to 'new ProviderDigest("SUN")'

Peeking at the source codes of iText (5.5.1-SNAPSHOT), I find the followings code fragments suspicious:

1. MakeSignature.java line 142 - 145

   *hashAlgorithm* = externalSignature.getHashAlgorithm() is called and then used in

   DigestAlgorithms.digest(data, externalDigest.getMessageDigest(*hashAlgorithm*));
2. PrivateKeySignature.java line 76

   Since I am using PrivateKeySignature, I peek at PrivateKeySignature.java and find that it returns its private class member hashAlgorithm and this is how it obtains the value during Construction (line 76):

   this.*hashAlgorithm* = 
   DigestAlgorithms.getDigest(DigestAlgorithms.getAllowedDigests(*hashAlgorithm*));
3. DigestAlgorithms.java methods  getAllowedDigests() and getDigest()

   In turn, getAllowedDigests() returns the OID of the algorithm if the algorithm name is found in the allowedDigests hash map (2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1 in my case), otherwise it returns null.

   getDigest gets the digest name back from the OID using the digestNames hash map.

   However, the name in digestNames hash map that corresponds to the OID is SHA256, not SHA-256.

As a result, the final digest name got was "SHA256" as opposed to "SHA-256" and "SHA256" was causing the NoSuchAlgorithm exception in SUN provider.

(I tried getting a message digest instance directly using the SUN provider. It succeeded for SHA-256 but threw the same exception I am reporting here for SHA256.

Is this a problem with iText when using JCE providers other than BC?

Appreciate if anyone could shed some light on my problem.

Comment: JCE indeed does not define "SHA256" as alias for SHA-256. Can you modify iText' digestNames hash map and replace 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1->SHA256 entry with 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1->SHA-256?

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I think that would solve my problem but I am not sure whether this is the correct way to go. Anyway I will give it  a try first.

Comment: I can get pass the MessageDigest.getInstance successfully if I modify the mapping as advised. However, I am hit by the "no such algorithm" exception immediately when it comes to Signature.getInstance() (this time it is SHA-256withRSA when it is expecting SHA256withRSA, I believe). It seems that there is a problem with the assumption that the same algorithm name (e.g. SHA-256 ) for digest can be used as the prefix for the Signature Algorithm as the algorithm names are not consistent across providers (e.g. SHA256 vs SHA-256).

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary workaround, I added the followings to PrivateKeySignature.java:

// Temporary fix - to remove hyphenation in hashAlgorithm name
//        String signMode = hashAlgorithm + "with" + encryptionAlgorithm;
        String signMode = hashAlgorithm.replaceAll("-","") + "with" + encryptionAlgorithm;
// End Temporary fix

It works for me at least for now. Has to investigate how standard names of different algorithms in different context go before a long term solution can be devised, I believe.